# Will it create an object for the below code?

Tags: c#

```
if(new string[] {constants.username,Constants.Lowercase}.contains("test"))
```

The code will create an object or not ? please help

Comment: It will create a new array each time, yes. But if they actually are constants... what is there to test here?

Comment: Why do you care about this small array? The code is readable and maintainable. I would declare the array before the `if`-statement and give it a meaningful name though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm going to have to intervene there; allocations of small objects *do* matter, very very much ... *if* it is in a hot code path. If this is in a button click on the UI... not so much. But: allocations are never free.

Comment: This code will be inside a For-Loop and this loop will run more than 20000 time  per day

Comment: @MarcGravell: that's why i've asked _why_ he cares about it. He hasn't said that he has any (peformance) issues. But even if, i'm pretty sure that the main-reason for it is somewhere else.

Comment: @Vengatesh.s 20,000 times is nothing... but indeed, allocating *unnecessarily* in a non-trivial `for` loop is not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will create a new string array each time.

Options:

If they actually are constants: `switch`:

```
switch(value) {
    case Constants.UserName:
    case Constants.LowerCase:
       // ...
       break;
}
```

If they are "unchanging but not `const`", then maybe a `static readonly` instance of `string[]` / `HashSet<string>` initialized in a static constructor (or whatever the scope is in which they don't change).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you  will create an instance of a string array
and if you want to see what's hapening under the cover

```
if (new string[] { "a", "b" }.Contains("c")) ;
```

The IL Generated from this will look  like  the follwing

```
 IL_0001: ldc.i4.2     
    IL_0002: newarr       [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_0007: dup          
    IL_0008: ldc.i4.0     
    IL_0009: ldstr        "a"
    IL_000e: stelem.ref   
    IL_000f: dup          
    IL_0010: ldc.i4.1     
    IL_0011: ldstr        "b"
    IL_0016: stelem.ref   
    IL_0017: ldstr        "c"
```

The `newarr`  is the IL instruction responsable for the creation of the new object
Take a look here  [OpCodes.Newarr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "new" always indicates that an object is being created. In this case the object will be valid in the if-statement only. After the statement the object will be released and cleaned-up by the garbage collector.

Comment: "The keyword "new" always indicates that an object is being created" - no it doesn't; `new DateTime(2017, 7, 17)` - zero objects.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that new DateTime(..) will create a new object of DateTime with the specified arguments. new can be used fas an: 1) Operator 2) Modifier 3) Restrictor

Comment: `DateTime` *isn't an object*, at least not in the allocation sense. It can be *made into* an object via boxing, but that's different

Comment: it's a structure?

Comment: Yes, `DateTime` is a `struct`

Comment: @Xzibitee  take a look  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator   to  understand  what Marc is talking about

Comment: But it will create an instance of the struct, which is an object

Comment: That's sort of a semantic argument about what defines an object, but in most senses: it isn't an object unless it is boxed (although it can be *treated* as one, via boxing). It depends a *lot* on the exact terminology you are using, though; for example, at the IL level, value-types (`struct`s) are "classes" (`.class public auto ansi serilizable sealed beforefieldinit DateTime`, in this case).

Comment: Yes, just read the documentation. Thanks for the correction^^

Comment: @MarcGravell you might point out that struct uses initobj as IL and new object uses newobj